# How to calculate the marks of selected student and subject dynamically in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not able to calculate marks of particular student based on particular subject **(both student name and subject are as dropdown list)** from another table.

***Here is how table looks like:***
[image]

Comment: The answer is probably something to do with pivot tables, but I'm not going to do your homework for you. You also get better results asking on StackOverflow if you frame your problem better. Remember no-one here has seen this spreadsheet nor actually knows what you're trying to do, so you need to explain. It is likely that questions written like yours will be closed without a proper answer otherwise, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX()/MATCH()` can give you expected result. Try-

```
=INDEX(B3:D7,MATCH(F3,A3:A7,0),MATCH(G3,B2:D2,0))
```

[image]